# SSE2 packed 8-bit integer signed multiply (high-half): Decomposing a m128i (16x8 bit) into two m128i (8x16 each) and repack

Tags: c++, intel, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to multiply two `m128i` byte per byte (8 bit signed integers).

The problem here is overflow. My solution is to store these 8 bit signed integers into 16 bit signed integers, multiply, then pack the whole thing into a `m128i` of 16 x 8 bit integers.

Here is the `__m128i mulhi_epi8(__m128i a, __m128i b)` emulation I made:

```
inline __m128i mulhi_epi8(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    auto a_decomposed = decompose_epi8(a);
    auto b_decomposed = decompose_epi8(b);

    __m128i r1 = _mm_mullo_epi16(a_decomposed.first, b_decomposed.first);
    __m128i r2 = _mm_mullo_epi16(a_decomposed.second, b_decomposed.second);

    return _mm_packs_epi16(_mm_srai_epi16(r1, 8), _mm_srai_epi16(r2, 8));
}
```

`decompose_epi8` is implemented in a non-simd way:

```
inline std::pair<__m128i, __m128i> decompose_epi8(__m128i input)
{
    std::pair<__m128i, __m128i> result;

    // result.first     =>  should contain 8 shorts in [-128, 127] (8 first bytes of the input)
    // result.second    =>  should contain 8 shorts in [-128, 127] (8 last bytes of the input)

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        result.first.m128i_i16[i]   = input.m128i_i8[i];
        result.second.m128i_i16[i]  = input.m128i_i8[i + 8];
    }

    return result;
}
```

This code works well. My goal now is to implement a simd version of this for loop. I looked at the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) but I can't find a way to do this. I guess shuffle could do the trick but I have trouble conceptualising this.

Comment: Try `_mm_unpacklo_epi8` and `_mm_unpackhi_epi8`

Comment: @Lawrence I will give it a try, thanks

Comment: @Lawrence `_mm_unpacklo_epi8` won't help much with signed unpacking. With SSE4.1 `_mm_cvtepi8_epi16` might be an option.

Comment: @Lawrence, actually, `_mm_unpack{lo,hi}_epi8` could work, since you can unpack the data bytes into the upper half of each 16bit word (and use `_mm_mulhi_epi16` for multiplication). I think you still need to either shift (or cleverly permute) the multiplication result, since I don't think there is a variant of `_mm_packs_epi16` which shifts to the right instead of saturating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to do signed multiplication, you need to sign-extend each byte to 16bit words, or move them into the upper half of each 16bit word. Since you pack the results back together afterwards, you can split the input into odd and even bytes, instead of the higher and lower half. <strike>Then sign-extension of the odd bytes can be done by arithmetically shifting all 16bit parts to the right</strike> You can extract the odd bytes by masking out the even bytes, and to get the even bytes, you can shift all 16bit parts to the left (both need to be multiplied by `_mm_mulhi_epi16`).

The following should work with SSE2:

```
__m128i mulhi_epi8(__m128i a, __m128i b)
{
    __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi16(0xff00);
    // mask higher bytes:
    __m128i a_hi = _mm_and_si128(a, mask);
    __m128i b_hi = _mm_and_si128(b, mask);

    __m128i r_hi = _mm_mulhi_epi16(a_hi, b_hi);
    // mask out garbage in lower half:
    r_hi = _mm_and_si128(r_hi, mask);

    // shift lower bytes to upper half
    __m128i a_lo = _mm_slli_epi16(a,8);
    __m128i b_lo = _mm_slli_epi16(b,8);
    __m128i r_lo = _mm_mulhi_epi16(a_lo, b_lo);
    // shift result to the lower half:
    r_lo = _mm_srli_epi16(r_lo,8);

    // join result and return:
    return _mm_or_si128(r_hi, r_lo);
}
```

Note: a previous version used shifts to sign-extend the odd bytes. On most Intel CPUs this would increase P0 usage (which needs to be used for multiplication as well). Bit-logic can operate on more ports, so this version should have better throughput.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps!

Comment: Nice update.  Agreed that looks like a better balance of mul/shift vs. other uops.  Skylake can run integer shift/mul on p0 or p1, but getting more uops that can use p5 into the mix is still good.  Good for Ryzen, too: even though mul and shift run on separate ports, they're each only 1c throughput.  (vs. 4/clock throughput for `pand`/`pxor` that can run on Ryzen's P0123)